# Is this atomic pointer swap pattern safe?

Tags: c++, thread-safety, c++17, atomic

The goal of the code/pattern below is to achieve high read performance. The read happens with very high frequency, and the write (update) is very infrequent. So I naturally would avoid using an exclusive lock like a mutex in both read/update. I also don't want to use a reader/writer lock approach because the high frequency of read operations will likely starve the update thread.

So, the pattern I propose is to use atomic raw pointers and swap. The read operation will just dereference the atomic pointer. The update operation will construct the new data on the heap and have an atomic pointer that points to it. Then swap them.

The swap doesn't have to be atomic. I just need to avoid a data race that causes pointer data corruption and crashes. So there is a time window where a read thread will already load the old data pointer and about to dereference it. I need to ensure I don't delete the old data pointer until all lingering read threads that have a reference to old data pointers are gone (read is non-blocking). That is why I sleep a bit after the swap. Then I delete the old data pointer.

Is there any hole in the implementation for thread safety? I couldn't use `atomic<shared_ptr>` because that is only in C++20, I think. So this is like a poor man's job for what couldn't been done with `atomic<shared_ptr>`. There is thread synchronization because of atomic, but still not the performance impact of an exclusive lock or a reader/writer lock.

```cpp
std::atomic<vector<string>*> data;

// Read thread (happen with extremely high frequency):
string& Read() {
  return data->load()->at(1);
}

// Update thread (happen infrequently):
void Update() {
  std::atomic<vector<string>*> newData = new std::vector<string>();
  // insert new data to newData ...
  // ....
 
  // swap pointers (swap as whole doesn't need to be atomic, but set pointers should be atomic)
  newData.store(data.exchange(newData));

  // sleep a bit so any read thread that already has gotten the old data pointer can
  // still get the old value before we delete the old data pointer
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);

  // delete the old data (After swap, newData points to old data)
  delete newData.load();
}
```

Comment: Typical case where I wish we had garbage collection...

Comment: @MarcGlisse yes in C#, I wouldn't need to do the hack of sleep and then delete. But this pattern should be quite common where high read perf is required (i.e. can't use lock). My main question is there any hole in the implementation. I know people in Facebook did something similar with shared_ptr. But they have bugs in that they think shared_ptr set/get is atomic; it is not. The above code can be implemented as atomic<shared_ptr> in C++20  I think.

Comment: There is no guarantee that `Read()` will have a valid `vector*` pointer after `load()` exits and before calling `at()`. The `sleep()` does not guarantee that the `vector*` remains alive long enough. The system could context-switch to another thread that could easily take longer than 100ms to run, then context-switch back to `Update()` before `Read()`, destroying the `vector` prematurely. This kind of situation is where you really need reference-counting (even if just manually instead of via `shared_ptr`), or a reader/writer lock.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, I agree. And 100ms is just a number I put there to make the point. I could do 1000ms or even several seconds because delete doesn't have to happen immediately as long as it happens in the "future", just like garbage collection. To be safe, I can modify the code to add "to-be-deleted pointers" to a list and clean up much later where in reality they are safe.

Comment: @Kenneth that doesn't really solve the race condition, because you are still depending on timing, rather than a clear "this is ok to use", "this is ok to delete now" kind of signaling

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Theoretically, it is not going to be 100%. But in terms of probability, if it is lower than normal crashing bugs, then it is no worse. As I pointed out earlier, reader/writer lock can't used because they don't have built-in starvation prevention. atomic<shared_ptr> is then the next best option without involving locks IMO. Wouldn't you agree?

Comment: If your code relies on random sleeps for correctness you obviously have a bug and most likely an architectural problem at hand. You can simply use a counter to know when it's safe to delete the old data (which is what the atomic shared pointer stuff does behind your back).

Comment: If performance is critical, you might want to look into an user space RCU library, to handle the memory cleanup safely (sleep won't be enough). If your application is short lived, you might want to just leak the vector..

Answer (score 4):

The code you have written is not "safe" by any good definition of that term. When it comes to writing good threading code, it shouldn't be about the "probability" that something will go wrong. You should *assume* that it will go wrong and use tools to make sure that it *cannot* go wrong.

This situation is what the [atomic `shared_ptr` accessor functions are made for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic). They've been around since C++11 (though they're deprecated in C++20, since `atomic<shared_ptr>` exists).

```
std::shared_ptr<vector<string>> data;

// Read thread (happen with extremely high frequency):
string& Read() {
  auto local_data = atomic_load(&data);
  //If `data` gets changed now, the destructor of `local_data` will take care of it.
  return local_data->at(1);
}

// Update thread (happen infrequently):
void Update() {
  auto newData = std::make_shared<std::vector<string>>();
  // insert new data to newData ...
  // ....
 
  // swap pointers (swap as whole doesn't need to be atomic, but set pointers should be atomic)
  newData = atomic_exchange(&data, newData);

  //Destructor takes care of deleting the old.
}
```

The primary caveat of these functions is that they exhibit UB if `data` is ever `null` when you call one of them. So... don't do that. This means you *cannot* call `Update` until `data` has been given memory to manage.

So you'll need to initialize `data` with something outside of calls to `Update`.

The design of this API is such that, when the time comes to switch to C++20's `atomic<shared_ptr>`, all you need to do is change the type used for `data`.

Comment: thanks. And when switching to atomic<shared_ptr>, I assume atomic_exchange should also be changed to newData = data.exchange(newData)?

Comment: @Kenneth: No need; [`atomic_exchange<T>` when given an `atomic<T>` is defined to be equivalent to calling `exchange` on that `atomic<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_exchange). Most of the atomic member functions have non-member equivalents named `atomic_*`.